Finite p-group $G$ of exponent $>p$ with all elements outside $\Phi(G)$ of order $p$
Does there exist a finite $p$-group $G$ of exponent $>p$, such that $o(g)=p$ for all $g\in G\setminus\Phi(G)$?

What does the notation $\Phi(G)$ mean, please?

If you picked a minimal generating set for $G$ coming from the vector space $G/\Phi(G)$, wouldn't the product of generators also have order dividing $p$, meaning $G$ would have to have exponent $p$?

@GerryMyerson $\Phi(G)$ is the Frattini subgroup: the intersection of its maximal subgroups. For a finite $p$-group $G$, $G/\Phi(G)$ is the largest quotient that is $p$-elementary abelian.

@SteveD No, in an non-abelian group, a product of elements of order $p$ can have larger order. Just think of the dihedral group of order 8, which is generated by elements of order 2.

@YCor: right, but by hypothesis that product is outside $\Phi(G)$ and so has order $p$.

But i guess this still fails for intertwined elements like the commutator $[x,y]=(yx)^{-1}(xy)$, a product of elements of order $p$ that lands in the Frattini subgroup.

The group has a high proportion of element with order $p$, but I don't know of any results giving upper bounds on this proportion.

One trivial case is $p=2$. Lift a basis of $G/\Phi(G)$ to get a generating subset consisting of elements of order 2 with pairwise products of order 2, thus commuting; thus $G$ is abelian.

Geoff Robinson has deleted his answer, but he pointed out that we can reduce to the case when $G$ has a central subgroup $Z$ of order $p$ with $Z < \Phi(G)$ such that $G/Z$ has exponent $p$, and we could assume also that $Z$ is the last nontrivial term in the lower central series of $G$. Since groups of exponent $3$ are well understood (they have class at most $3$ for example), it should at least be possible to investigate and perhaps resolve  the case $p=3$.

What I figured out (and maybe coincides with GR's deleted answer). Let $G$ be a minimal example, so every proper quotient of $G$ has exponent $\le p$. Then the center $Z$ of $G$ is cyclic (otherwise, there is a quotient of exponent $p^2$), say with generator $c$. Since $G/Z$ has exponent $p$, $x^p\in Z$ for all $x$. Then $Z$ has order $p$ (otherwise $c\in\Phi(G)$; pick $x\notin\Phi(G)$, then $xc$ has order $p^2$ and is not in $\Phi(G)$, contradiction). In particular, $Z$ is the last term in the lower central series, and $\Phi(G)=[G,G]$.

Another remark is that any example has nilpotency class $\ge p$ (because for every $p$-group of nilpotency class is $<p$, then the elements of order $\le p$ form a subgroup, by Lazard's correspondence).

Yes, there are such groups, at least for p=7. This was  constructed by Khukhro in Mat. Sb. 118 (1982), 567-575. This is a link for the paper in English:
https://www.mathnet.ru/links/0f7158d0f38021d770563b4ae9c46981/sm2833_eng.pdf
As Khukhro points out in p. 219 of his book "Nilpotent groups and their automorphisms" this groups is "kind of a "monster" in the theory of finite p-groups." It is a 2-generated group.
As you can see from these references, the key term for this question is the so-called Hughes conjecture. That is known to be true for p=2 or 3, so in particular, as suggested in the comments, there aren't examples of groups satisfying the hypothesis of the question when p<5.
From Remark 2 at the end of Khukhro's paper, probably there aren't 2-generated examples when p=5.
Counterexamples are known for Hughes conjecture for p=5,7,11,13,17,19, and expected to exist for all primes. I would expect (extremely complicated) examples to exist for this question for any p>5. Maybe not for p=5.
